# How to create a custom .desktop-file

Tags: slingshot, app-shortcuts

everyone. I use zotero for my studies and downloaded a tar.gz-file from their website. When I extract it, it has an executable shell script that launches the programme. I wanted to be able to start Zotero from slingshot instead of having to browse to the folder every time I want to open it. So I created my own .desktop file which is called zotero.desktop and I created it while running scratch as root and placed it in `/usr/share/applications/`
This is the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Zotero
Comment=Bibliografisch programma
Exec=/home/lieven/ICT/Configuratie en Setup/Zotero_linux-x86_64/zotero
Icon=/home/lieven/ICT/Configuratie en Setup/Zotero_linux-x86_64/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
Categories=Utility
Terminal=false
```

But when I open slingshot and type in Zotero, it isn't listed as an entry. This is also the case after logging out and restarting the computer. What can I do to be able to open Zotero from within slingshot?

Comment: I think the problem with `Exec`...are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: You may use https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/ to create the launcher, if you prefer a GUI alternative to .desktop file editing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct content of `zotero.desktop` as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Zotero
Comment=Bibliografisch programma
Exec=/home/lieven/ICT/Configuratie\ en\ Setup/Zotero_linux-x86_64/zotero
Icon=/home/lieven/ICT/Configuratie\ en\ Setup/Zotero_linux-x86_64/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
Categories=Utility
Terminal=false
```

Path with space should contain a backslash.

Also make `zotero.desktop` executable through Terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/zotero.desktop
```

**PS:** No need to get into system files, `*.desktop` with same success can be placed in `~/.local/share/applications`. In this case, command to change permissions of an executable file will look like this:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked flawlessly. Thanks for the tip to put it in the user's configuration folder, but there are other users on the machine that use the programme, that's why I put it in /usr/share/applications/.

Comment: @user72805, I'm glad that my answer helped you. Offtop: my English is very bad?

Comment: You can see that you're not a native speaker, but it's good enough for getting the message across. It's fine, but I'm not a native speaker either :-).

Comment: I'm trying to setup my desktop file but for some reason it doesn't work. My exec is `Exec=/home/jena/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-qtconsole --kernel=ir` (note the space before the parameter). Clicking the icon in launcher will show icon on the dock for a moment, but then it disappears. If I put backslash there (i.e. `jupyter-qtconsole\ --kernel=ir`) then it disappears from the launcher. Same if I put it in either single- or double-quotes. If I remove the parameter, it launches fine, but with default python kernel, while I need R kernel. So clearly the space before parameter is the problem. Any idea?

Comment: aha so apparently the `=` is the [problem](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html#exec-variables) - does anybody know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

this is for raspberry pi where you run your program in a terminal

create a desktop file (`runthis.desktop`) in `/home/pi/.config/autostart`

copy these lines to the file (`runthis.desktop`)

```
[Desktop Entry] 

Encoding=UTF-8

Type=Application

Name=RootCam

Comment=

Exec=x-terminal-emulator --working-directory=/home/pi/projects/RootCam/main -e /home/pi/projects/RootCam/main &

StartupNotify=true

Terminal=true
Hidden=false
```

change working directory and executed program to your desire

```
reboot pi
```

tell your parents you love them

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient way of managing `.desktop` files via GUI interface too: [AppEditor](https://github.com/donadigo/appeditor)