# How can I get AppImages to show up in the Applications Menu?

Tags: applications, release-hera

I am using elementary OS 5.1 Hera. If I install some AppImage file in my home directory, I don't find its app icon in the Applications Menu.

Comment: I'm not so sure what problem is, but if you'd like to add any programs to your application menu just try this https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/how-to-create-a-custom-desktop-file

Answer (score 7):

AppImages are not automatically integrated in elementary. I faced the same problem for an application I needed. (I second the suggestion from [@cassidy-james-blaede](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/308/cassidy-james-blaede), use Flatpak if possible, in my case it wasn't)

Fortunately the AppImage documentation has some nice information about integrating them with [Desktop Environment](https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/run-appimages.html#integrating-appimages-into-the-desktop)

There are two available solutions:

- [appimaged](https://github.com/AppImage/appimaged): is a daemon that monitors the system and integrates AppImages
- [AppImageLauncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher):  is a helper application for Linux distributions serving as a kind of “entry point” for running and integrating AppImages

`appimaged` can be installed by downloading the AppImage from the GitHub Release page and installing it from command line. I would say this solution is not the preferred one, you can find detailed instructions [here](https://github.com/AppImage/appimaged#install).

The suggested solution (by me, I think is the easiest) is to install `AppImageLauncher`:

1. Download the `.deb` from the [GitHub Release](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases) page
2. Install it either:

   1. from terminal, with `$ sudo dpkg -i {name}.deb` from the directory you have downloaded the file into
   2. using a GUI tool like [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/) (you can install it from AppCenter)
3. You can now double click on `.AppImage` files and have them integrated in the system

Comment: +1 `AppImageLauncher` is easily a great app to handle this for you.

Answer (score 4):

AppImages don't automatically add .desktop files to the appropriate FreeDesktop standard place needed to show up in the Applications Menu. There is [a daemon you can install](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit) to automatically manage AppImage .desktop launchers, but I don't have experience with that directly.

If you have the choice, it's typically recommended to use Flatpak apps on elementary OS instead of AppImage because elementary has [officially backed Flatpak](https://blog.elementary.io/elementary-appcenter-flatpak/), elementary OS supports Flatpak out of the box, and elementary developers have put [significant work into](https://blog.elementary.io/updates-for-october-2019/) making sure it's easy to install and update Flatpak apps throughout the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Great answers. Another way to create desktop entries is by using the AppEditor ( https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/ ).

It works for appimages and any other type of application.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [AppImageLauncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher), it is a really great tool and if the AppImages support it it will even keep them up to date.